# Color Profile keeps resetting to "default"

Tags: display, mojave, screen, color

I had this problem before with **High Sierra** and now I just updated to **Mojave** and still the same issue.

Basically **sometimes** (sometimes after i reboot, sometimes after it goes to sleep, sometimes after a new boot), my mac decides to revert back to the default color profile that is at the top of the list.

I don't understand why? maybe this is normal since it happened on both **High Sierra** and **Mojave**? Does someone had similar "issue"? Is there a way of **not** making this happen?

[image]

Comment: Check the box for "Show Profiles for this display only". You **should never use** anything not designed for that display. Adobe98 is not a screen profile it is an output profile. I see some serious misunderstanding of how profiles should work, here. [The trouble then is, explaining how profiling works could take a whole book, or in fact several.]

Comment: Golden rule, in one sentence... Set your screen to your **calibrated** screen profile, set Photoshop etc to your desired **output** profile. Done. [Generic 'LG Ultrawide' is what the manufacturer thinks your screen should look like. Calibrated is what it has been accurately measured to using a colorimeter.]

Comment: Yes you are right I have no understanding of how profiles works and I wrongly use it as a "tone balance". the reason of why I don't have the default is just pure personal preference. I don't do color correction on my mac nor nothing related with colors and I just wanted a more pleasant color to my eyes compared to the default one. but I understand what you are saying thanks. I should keep the intended one for my monitor.